# Create Android Studio compatible library from OpenGL C++ Project

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, opengl, glu

I am currently trying to create a library file (e.g. .so) from an existing and working OpenGL C++ Visual Studio 19 project.

My plan is to create this library to call functions from the VS-project within Android Studio, as I am trying to extend the AR-Core sample "[Hello_AR_c](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_c)" which should ultimately create an android .apk containing my OpenGL C++ functionality.

I am using Windows 10-64 and Visual Studio19 as well as the current version of Android Studio.

---

I attempted to create a new Static Library (Android) project in VS and add it to my working solution. After that I included my existing source code files from my OpenGL project and tried to build the android project as ".so".
After fixing some errors which did not appear in the original project I struggled to get rid of the errors in "[GLU.h](https://pastebin.com/5CT4eJtK)", which prevents me from building it. Nevertheless I am unsure if solving the errors will lead to a compiling and correctly working version.

Error examples:

E0338   more than one instance of overloaded function "gluQuadricCallback" has 'C' linkage  GLU.h   232

`void APIENTRY gluQuadricCallback(GLUquadric *qobj,GLenum which, void (CALLBACK* fn)())`

E0018   expected a ')'  GLU.h   364

`typedef void (CALLBACK* GLUquadricErrorProc) (GLenum);`

I expect that this errors come from a different platform toolset or something similar, as in my android project it is Clang 5.0, where as in my working project it is set to Visual Studio 2017.

Does somebody have any idea for this problem of mine? Is there maybe an easier way to combine a visual studio OpenGL project with an Android studio project?

Thank you in advance.

Error examples:
[image: Errorlist of Glu.h]

Android Config - Not building:
[image: Android Config - Not building]
OpenGl project - working:
[image: OpenGl project - working]

Comment: fyi Android does not use OpenGL but OpenGL ES 2.0+ which has a different/more limited API